# Find the two Laurent series for $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^3-z^4}$ that involve powers of z, and state their domains of convergence.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I'm working on the following problem: Find the two Laurent series for $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^3-z^4}$ that involve powers of z, and state their domains of convergence. I'm not sure how to go about it, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are which point are you taking the expansion?

Comment: That is not mentioned in the problem. All I have been given is the above unfortunately :(

Comment: Considering the function has two poles at $z=0$ and $z=1$, I would take it to mean you are supposed to find the series expansions about those two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not specified, I suggest finding expansions about $z = 0$. Since Laurent series converge on "annuli" in the complex plane centered at the point of expansion, we look for annuli centered at the origin. Note that $f$ has singularities at $z = 0, 1$. Thus there are two "annuli" on which $f$ is holomorphic: $\{0 < |z| < 1\}$ and $\{1 < |z|\}$. Note that in the former, using the fact that $|z| < 1$, we can expand a geometric series: $$f(z) = \frac{1/z^3}{1 - z} = \frac{1}{z^3}\sum_{k = 0}^\infty z^k = \sum_{k = -3}^\infty z^k$$ which gives the Laurent series.

This trick involving geometric series can also be used for the case when $|z| > 1$. As a hint, note that $|z| > 1$ implies $|1/z| < 1$, so try to expand $f$ using a geometric series with $1/z$ as the ratio.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Would you be able to explain what the problem means by "the two Laurent Series"? Also, why are we allowed to center our annuli about 0 if 0 is a singularity?

Comment: 1. The coefficients in the Laurent expansion are different in different annuli. So in this case, the expansion in the annulus $\{0 < |z| < 1\}$ has different coefficients from the expansion in $\{1 < |z|\}$. Thus the problem is asking you to find these two distinct expansions. 2. The annuli are centered at $z = 0$ because we are expanding about $z = 0$. The point $z = 0$ is excluded from the annuli, so it isn't a problem. We just want $f$ to be holomorphic in the annuli.